# Python opencv + flask, VideoCamera turning on but not displaying video feed

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I tried to get the video feed from camera to desktop browser using flask and opencv. When I run the main.py file and open the local ip adress in browser my led indicator for camera turns on but it never displayed video feed on page. What am I missing?

My project structure looks like this:

```
├── VideoStreaming/
│   ├── camera.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── index.html
```

camera.py file:

```
import cv2
# defining face detector
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
ds_factor = 0.6

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # capturing video
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        # releasing camera
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        # extracting frames
        ret, frame = self.video.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=ds_factor, fy=ds_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face_rects = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for (x, y, w, h) in face_rects:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            break
        # encode OpenCV raw frame to jpg and displaying it
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)

        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

main.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # rendering webpage
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        #get camera frame
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # defining server ip address and port
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port='5000', debug=True)
```

and this is the index.html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
    <img id="bg" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I clicked on the local ip adress displayed on PyCharm and it opened by deafult on Microsoft Edge, when I tried to open it on Google Chrome it worked. In case someone gets similar problems it should try it with another browser.